# Why Haskell need Data.Sequence when we already have list?

Tags: list, haskell, sequence, evaluation, eager

List is a default data type of Haskell, why we still need Data.Sequence? Does Data.Seq mean something like a C style array that could be accessed randomly?

If yes, I would suppose this means Data.Sequence is stored with fixed memory buffer and thus, eager evaluated type. Just a guess, would you help to correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The list type is a single-linked list. As such, prepend, `head` and `tail` are all O(1). However, `++` is O(n) in the size of the left-hand list.

By contrast, `Data.Sequence` is a balanced tree, so most operations on it are O(log n). That's not as fast as O(1), but it's potentially much faster O(n). In other words, you can join sequences faster than lists, but prepend is slightly slower.

Other than that, both data structures have quite similar properties; they're both lazy, they're both referentially transparent. (Sequence has to be finite though.)

See also the opening remarks from [the documentation for Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html):

> General purpose finite sequences. Apart from being finite and having strict operations, sequences also differ from lists in supporting a wider variety of operations efficiently.

The underlying algorithm is apparently [described here](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.html). (In particular, includes a nice diagram.)

If you want *arrays*, you need to look at `Data.Array` and/or `Data.Vector`.

Comment: `cons`, `snoc`, `head` and `last` counterparts are all amortized *O(1)* for `Data.Sequence`.

Comment: Also, isn't `Data.Sequence.Seq` a finger tree?

Comment: "has to be finite" means that `Seq` is lazy in the elements but strict in the spine, right?

Comment: @chi Yeah. Presumably to keep the tree branches balanced.

Comment: @chi: Also, `Seq` keeps the number of current elements in an `Int`. I guess that many `Seq` functions use that `Int` to automatically balance the tree. An infinite `Seq` would lead to interesting behaviour.

Comment: @chi, it's *semantically* strict in the spine, but the spine is *lazy* to achieve amortization and fast `fmap`, `traverse`, `<*>`, etc.